# (datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.datetime.today()).days giving -1

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying this `(datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.datetime.today()).days` giving -1

and expecting a value 0 instead I am getting -1. In this case I have add 1 to the result

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a micro seconds difference while you are subtracting the dates.
Suppose datetime.datetime.today() is giving

```
>>> datetime.datetime.today()`
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 17, 17, 33, 45, 243739)
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 17, 17, 33, 45, 727018)
```

From this you can see that both are ran in the same seconds timestamp but micro-fraction difference. 
So, when you do

```
(datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.datetime.today()).days
```

you will get -1 day as result, which is a correct result.

Answer (score 5):

`timedelta` objects must always have a *positive* number of seconds and microseconds; the way a negative delta is expressed is by using a negative number of days. The seconds and microseconds then count in the other direction from those negative days.

`datetime.datetime.today()` produces a full date and time, complete with microseconds. The second call is executed a fraction of a second later, and subtracting the two gives you a negative timedelta.

So as a result, you get a timedelta with -1 day difference and a positive number of seconds *almost* equal to a full day, except for a fraction of a second:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 21, 7, 27, 43, 523202)
>>> datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.datetime.today()
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86399, 999990)
```

Note the 86399 seconds and 999990 microseconds in the resulting `timedelta` object. The difference is not a full day, it is only 10 microseconds.

If you need an 'absolute' number, use the [`timedelta.total_seconds()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.datetime.today()).total_seconds()
-8e-06
```

Divide that again by 86400 to get a number of days:

```
>>> int((datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.datetime.today()).total_seconds() / 86400)
0
>>> int((datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=2, seconds=10) - datetime.datetime.today()).total_seconds() / 86400)
-2
```

Alternatively, add 1 to the `.days` attribute of a `timedelta` when `seconds` or `microseconds` is non-zero:

```
td = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.datetime.today()
days = td.days + (1 if td.seconds or td.microseconds else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to store data in a variable:

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> a-a
datetime.timedelta(0)
>>> (a-a).days
0
```

You will get the zero.

Although this is the proper explanation for your answer:
[Martin Pieters' Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361098/6918812)